# a question about interior and closure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$C$ is an non-empty subset of $R^n$ which has the following property: if $x,y \in C$, then $(x+y)/2 \in C$.

Let $a,b\in R^n$ such that $a \in C$ and $b \in $ interior of $C$. Prove that $(a+b)/2 \in $ interior of $C$.

If $a \in $ closure of $C$ and $b \in $ interior of $C$, does it still follow that $(a+b)/2 \in $ interior of $C$?

where a,b,x,y are all vectors in R^n, i type them as letters because i dont know how to type vectors. sorry for inconvenience!

i have tried to find a e>0 such that the open ball centered at p=(a+b)/2 with radius e is contained in C, but i failed.
i also tried the proof by contradiction: suppose p does not belong to interior of C. still,i did not get something useful.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It is helpful if you include the work you have doen towards this question so people can write answers which are at your level of knowledge and don't cover things you already know

Comment: From the tags of the question, I assume your definition of $x\in \int C$ is that there is $r>0$ such that the ball with center $x$ and radius $r$ is completely contained in $C$. Given that $a,b$ belong to the interior of $C$, there are $r_a,r_b>0$ such that $B(a;r_a),B(b;r_b)\subseteq C$. By the hypothesis, $(a+b)/2$ is an element in $C$. I think you can prove that the ball with center $(a+b)/2$ and center $r=\min\{r_a,r_b\}>0$ is completely contained in $C$.

Comment: @Wore Given a belongs to C and b belongs to the interior of C. not "a,b belong to interior of C"

Comment: Members of a vector space can and often are , denoted by letters. A letter can stand for anything, as long as you define your terms.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $f(x)=(x+a)/2.$ This is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^n$ onto $\mathbb R^n.$ Thus $f$ is an open map. Hence $f(\text {int }C)$ is an open set. But $f(\text {int }C)$ is the set of midpoints of segments from points of $\text {int }C$ to the point $a.$ Therefore $f(\text {int }C)\subset C.$  Thus $(b+a)/2 \in f(\text {int }C) \subset \text { int }C$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Take $r>0$ such that $B(b,r)=\{y: \|y-b\|<r\}\subset C.$

(1). When $a\in C$:  For any $x\in B((a+b)/2,r/2)$  we have $$\|(2x-a)-b)\|=2\|x-(a+b)/2\|<r,$$ $$\text {so }\quad 2x-a\in B(b,r)\subset C,$$ so $2x-a\in C$ so $x=((2x-a)+a)/2\in C.$ Hence $B((a+b)/2,r/2)\subset C.$

(2). When $a\in \bar C$: Take $a'\in C$ with $\|a'-a\|<r/2.$ By (1) we have $B((a'+b)/2,r/2)\subset C.$ Now for any  $x\in B((a+b)/2, r/4)$ we have $$\|x-(a'+b)/2\|\leq \|x-(a+b)/2\|+\|(a+b)/2-(a'+b)/2\|=$$ $$=\|x-(a+b)/2\|+\|(a-a')/2\|<r/4 +r/4=r/2,$$  so $x\in B((a'+b)/2,r/2)\subset C$ so  $x\in C.$ So $B((a+b)/2,r/4)\subset C.$

For (1), note that $2x-a$ is the point on the  line thru $a$ and $x$ that is twice as far from $a$ as $x$ is from $a.$ A diagram could clarify the  idea.